# Weighted mean deadlock: Value depending on value

Tags: sql, algorithm, sql-server-2008, math

Some background to help explain this difficult question first:

I have a database that estimates the reliability of users by comparing the values that they have submitted to a global average. Values range between 0 and 1.
So, where:

- Reliability of this particular user = `r`
- Average of this particular user's submitted values = `a`
- Global, "agreed upon" average = `g`

Reliability:

```
r = 1 - ABS(g - a)
```

This is how the reliability of each user is calculated.
Now, the Global, "agreed upon" average `g`, is calculated using a weighted mean, where the weighting is the `r` and the value is `a`. If there are 3 users in total:

```
  g = ((r1 * a1) + (r2 * a2) + (r3 * a3)) / (r1 + r2 + r3)
```

The problem is, that once users have a high reliability, they have a complete monopoly, and no new values can change this. Taking an example:

```
g was initially 0.5
user1 r was initially 0.5
user2 r was initially 0.5
user3 r was initially 0.5
```

Now, they will submit values one by one, and watch what happens:

```
user1 a is submitted, 1.0
user1 reliability goes slightly down because it differs from g (0.5)
user2 a is submitted, 1.0
user1 and user2 reliability go up to 100%, g is now 1.0.
user3 a is submitted, 0.0
user3 reliability goes down to 0%. g is still 1.0.
```

Since user3 has a very low reliability, the weighting does not have any effect at all on `g`. User3's reliability goes down because the values submitted differ completely from the global average. What can be done to make user3's submissions have **some** effect on the final value? Maybe I need to add some constant so that reliability never ends up completely zero (but close)?

Now, for the SQL code. I've added an SQL fiddle that demonstrates the problem:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3fd1/21
I've abstracted the code to keep it as short, but it's still quite long.

Table creation, stored procedures and trigger:

```
-- Stores user info
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users(
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Reliability] [float] NOT NULL
  )

-- Contains global averages from all users who submitted data
CREATE TABLE dbo.GlobalSubmission(
    GlobalSubmissionID  [int] NOT NULL,
    Name [varchar](50) NULL,
    GlobalAverage [float] NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserSubmission(
    SubValue float NOT NULL,
    GlobalSubmissionID int NOT NULL,
    UserID int NOT NULL,
)


GO

--Calculate the "ideal value", used for GlobalSubmission.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IdealValueCalc(@globalSubmissionID INT)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @tmpReliability TABLE (SubValue float, Reliability float)


INSERT INTO @tmpReliability
    SELECT AVG(us.SubValue) as SubValue, usr.Reliability Reliability FROM UserSubmission us
    JOIN Users usr 
    ON us.UserID = usr.UserID
    WHERE GlobalSubmissionID = @GlobalSubmissionID
    GROUP BY us.UserID, usr.Reliability

--Perform weighted mean calculations.
Return (SELECT SUM(SubValue * Reliability) / SUM(Reliability) FROM @tmpReliability)
END
go


--Calculate the reliability of one user.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetReliabilityForUser
(@userID int)
Returns Float
AS BEGIN
Return (SELECT 1 - AVG(ABS(db.userAvg - db.GlobalAverage))
    FROM (
      SELECT pmd.UserID,
            gs.GlobalAverage, 
            AVG(pmd.SubValue) as userAvg
      FROM UserSubmission pmd
      -- Joins average value for each user with "ideal" value from GlobalSubmission
      JOIN GlobalSubmission gs 
        ON gs.GlobalSubmissionID = pmd.GlobalSubmissionID
        WHERE pmd.UserID = 1
      GROUP BY pmd.UserID, gs.GlobalSubmissionID, gs.GlobalAverage
     ) db
     GROUP BY db.UserID)
End
go



CREATE TRIGGER trg_SubmissionComputation
ON UserSubmission 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    --Calculate this uer's reliability
    DECLARE @userID int = (SELECT TOP(1) UserID FROM inserted)
    DECLARE @userReliability float = dbo.GetReliabilityForUser(@userID)

    UPDATE Users
    SET Reliability=@userReliability
    WHERE UserID = @userID

    --Recalculate globalSubmission values:
    DECLARE @globalSubmissionID int = (SELECT TOP(1) GlobalSubmissionID FROM inserted)
    DECLARE @globalAverage float = dbo.IdealValueCalc(@globalSubmissionID)
        --The global average for this set of submissions has been recalculated. Now inserting:

    UPDATE GlobalSubmission
    SET GlobalAverage = @globalAverage 
    WHERE GlobalSubmissionID = @globalSubmissionID
END
GO
```

Testing it:

```
--Creating 3 new users
INSERT INTO Users
(UserID, Reliability)
values 
(1, 0.5),
(2, 0.5),
(3, 0.5)
GO

--Creating a new GlobalSubmission
INSERT INTO GlobalSubmission
(GlobalSubmissionID, NAME, GlobalAverage)
values (1, 'BOILER2B' , 0.5)
GO

--First, we will submit values of 1 for two users:
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (1.0, 1, 1); -- Value: 1.0, User 1, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (1.0, 1, 2); -- Value: 1.0, User 2, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (1.0, 1, 1); -- Value: 1.0, User 1, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (1.0, 1, 2); -- Value: 1.0, User 2, Submission 1
GO


--Now, we will submit values of 0 for the third user:
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0.0, 1, 3); -- Value: 0.0, User 3, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0.0, 1, 3); -- Value: 0.0, User 3, Submission 1
GO

SELECT * FROM Users -- This results in 0% reliability for the last user.

--If we create new users and add them, the reliability won't budge:
INSERT INTO Users
(UserID, Reliability)
values 
(4, 0.5),
(5, 0.5),
(6, 0.5),
(7, 0.5),
(8, 0.5)
GO


INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 4); -- Value: 0, User 4, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 5); -- Value: 0, User 5, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 6); -- Value: 0, User 6, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 7); -- Value: 0, User 7, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 8); -- Value: 0, User 8, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 4); -- Value: 0, User 4, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 5); -- Value: 0, User 5, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 6); -- Value: 0, User 6, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 7); -- Value: 0, User 7, Submission 1
GO
INSERT INTO UserSubmission values (0, 1, 8); -- Value: 0, User 8, Submission 1
GO


SELECT * FROM Users -- Even though we've added loads of new users suggesting 0 as value, the final value
-- is remaining 1.0, because when a new value (0) is submitted, it varies too much from the global average
--(1), causing the reliability of that user to go down, and that user ends up making no influence on the
-- global average!
```

Comment: @GuillermoRenéRamírez I don't think he's getting any errors, per se. He's more looking for algorithmic help.

Comment: @DavidKiger Nailed it.

Comment: Sorry, read "deadlock" and immediately tried to find some conflicting locks.

Comment: You've explained the problem well, but without knowing the answer you'd like to receive (as opposed to your current answer which you deem incorrect) how can we help? How about only calculating reliability after all user submissions have been made, if a majority of users submit and incorrect value your reliability ratings will be incorrect as well.

Comment: `How about only calculating reliability after all user submissions have been made?` that's very difficult. This is a crowdsourced system, the nature of it is that submissions will be sent randomly by different users. You are right, but the majority is not often wrong. It's called "wisdom of the crowd". Well, the answer I would like to receive would preferably change the algorithm so that new users submitting values would have **some** impact on the global average.

Comment: Have you considered using something like a moving average, so that older submissions do not impact the (current) reliability rating as much as more recent submissions?

Comment: @JakeP No idea how I can implement that, though.

Comment: David, like what @mcdowella describes in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative estimate that is still a bit ad hoc but doesn't ever produce weight 0.

1) For each user produce an exponentially decaying estimate of squared error. Start with a tunable arbitrary estimate K. Then every time the user produces a value a and the group mean is g produce a squared error E = (a - g) * (a - g) and change the estimate of squared error from before to after = before * x + E * (1 - x) where x is another tunable constant between 0 and 1 which tunes how fast old estimates decay. This estimate can never quite get down to zero, but because of the next step it might be as well to stop it decreasing below some tunable value.

2) To get a new global estimate use a weighted mean as before, but make the weights the reciprocal of the current estimate of squared error for that user.

If all the users were unbiased then the exponentially decaying estimates might end up as decent estimates of average squared error for each user, and then the weights would be the linear combination of estimates which minimises the expected squared error of the global estimate. Check: if the different users i submitted averages of Ni estimates from the same source then the mean squared error of each user's estimates would be 1/Ni so multiplying by the reciprocal of this would turn their averages into the original sum of estimates produced by each user and the weighted estimate would end up just pooling the estimates.

Comment: Some examples (not even expecting code, but mathematical examples) would really help. For example, working out the value of E, global estimate etc.. when two users submit 1.0 and one user submits 0.0 afterwards.

Comment: Its been a while, but should the formula for the moving average be E * x + before * (1 - x)?

Comment: `before` is the "current" value of a?

Comment: Whoops, a bit slow today, doesn't really matter whether it is E * x or before * x. @David, I believe "before" is the old "reliability" value. This formula describes an [Exponential Moving Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) of the squared error.

Comment: Damn, trying to implement this with SQL and it's really confusing. I'll give it another shot tomorrow, thinkingCapability is inversely proportional to hours after midnight :P

Comment: Yes, before is the old value before seeing a for a particular user, after is the newly computed value, and this is indeed an exponential moving average of the squared error.

Comment: @mcdowella So,
`after = before  * x + E * (1 - x)`
Let before=1.0, x=0.5, E=0. `after = 1 * 0.5 + 0 * (1-0.5)`
after=0.5. So reliability going down by half when error=0? Maybe it's my mistake.

Comment: What we are calculating here does indeed decrease with 0 error. It is no longer a measure of reliability, but a measure of squared error, so you would expect it to go down here. This makes sense because you weight estimates by the reciprocal of this, so a lower squared error means a larger weight - from 1/1.0 = 1 to 1/0.5 = 2.0. If you want to announce reliability, not squared error, you could announce the weight.

Comment: @mcdowella OK! Think I'm nearly there, though if I try to find the reciprocal of E when E is 0, I will get infinity (1/0). For now, I'm using a sort of hack ( IF E = 0 return SumOfValues/CountOfvalues). Would that be correct?

Comment: In theory, E should never go to 0, because it starts off non-zero and the lowest at each stage should be Ex, Ex^2, Ex^3... none of which is zero. In practice of course it could eventually get so small as to be zero. I suggest that you add e.g. E = max(E, verySmall) where verySmall is some tunable parameter, so it never gets below verySmall. Depending on where the values come from there may be some plausible value for this - if all numbers submitted are whole numbers you might set E = 0.25, as 0.5 is a plausible minimum error and 0.25 is this squared.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion, get rid of absolute differences. They make the math more difficult than it should be. Use square difference to keep stuff simple.

Keep track of sum and count of each user's submitted value.

g= (sum1*r1+sum2*r2+sum3*r3)/(count1*r1+count2*r2+count3*r3)

Initialize sums to 0.5, count to 1 and r to 1.0.

Whenever you receive a rating, update sum and count for that user, overall g, and reliability for every user using:

r = 1- (g - sum/count)^2.

Essentially, you are keeping track of ratings with some "prior". If you initialize count to a large number, the algorithm is resistant to errant submitted values, but takes more time to converge. Exact opposite is true if you reduce initial count (extreme case to 0).

Comment: What do `sum(x)` and `count(x)` represent please?

Comment: @David sum is the sum of all values received from a particular user. You do receive multiple values from a user, right?

Comment: ahh ok, got it now. Yes I do.

Comment: I can't really initialize sums and counts. They are taken from the database. I will initialize R to 1.0 though, and maybe I could add a constant to count?

Comment: Just tried yours. Here's the code for reliability with your algorithm:
`SELECT us.UserID, 1- (@g -POWER(SUM(us.SubValue) / COUNT(us.SubValue), 2)) Reliability FROM UserSubmission us
JOIN Users u
ON u.UserID = us.UserID
WHERE us.GlobalSubmissionID = 520
GROUP BY us.SubValue, us.UserID` This part, at least is behaving much like mine. When g=1.0, user1(average) = 1, user2(a)=1 and user3(a)=0,  the result is: user3(r) = 0, user2(r)=1.0 and user1(r)=1.0

Comment: @David You can try POWER( (SUM(us.SubValue)+0.5) / (COUNT(us.SubValue)+1), 2)  if you want to smooth your results with a little prior

Comment: No, it's the same as before, because it's not possible to change the values of sums and count. It's probably because the algorithm is run many hundreds of times: Every time there is a new submission, everything is recalculated.

Comment: @David Okay. Try it with the prior (  POWER( (SUM(us.SubValue)+0.5) / (COUNT(us.SubValue)+1), 2) ). Also try with adding different values to sum and count (5.0 and 10 maybe).

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the user's reliability until after the new global mean is computed.

```
g was initially "don't care"
user1 r was initially 0.5
user2 r was initially 0.5
user3 r was initially 0.5
```

Then

```
user1 a is submitted, 1.0
g = (0.5)*(1.0)/(0.5) = 1.0
user1 reliability = 1 - ABS (1 -1) = 1
user2 a is submitted, 1.0
g = ((1.0)*(1.0) + (0.5)*(1.0))/(1 + 0.5) = 1.0
user1 reliability = 1 - ABS (1 -1) = 1
user2 reliability = 1 - ABS (1 -1) = 1
user3 a is submitted, 0.0
g = ((1.0)*(1.0) + (1.0)*(1.0) + (0.5)*(0))/(1 + 1 + 0.5) = 0.8
user1 reliability = 1 - ABS (0.8 -1) = 0.8
user2 reliability = 1 - ABS (0.8 -1) = 0.8
user3 reliability = 1 - ABS (0.8 - 0.0) = 0.2
```

Comment: Thousands of submissions are sent. The order does not matter. I've tried it, I get good results at first, but as more are submitted it very quickly ends up zero.

Comment: @David - If you get thousands of 1's, and only a few 0's, you'd expect the people who voted 0 to get a reliability of 0.  The important part is that if the votes later shift toward a 50-50 split, that the reliability of the people who voted 0 goes up.

Comment: Yes, but if the votes shift to 50-50 later on, the reliability does not change, that's the thing!